# Make page scroll to certain point using div id's

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code halfway down my page:

```
<div id="last" style="height:10px; top:50px; background-color:black;"></div>
```

and the url looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/page.php#last
```

Top of the `#last` div is showing right at the top of the page but it should be `50px` lower down though.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `position: absolute`.

`<div id="last" style="height:10px; position: absolute; top:50px; background-color:black;"></div>`